# Multiplying command argument by factor

Tags: macros, lengths, calc

I am trying to use `calc` to perform a basic multiplication of arguments of a user-defined command, like this:

```
\def\Verdana#1{
 \normalfont
 \fontsize{#1}{#1 * \real{1.2}}
 \VerdanaFont
 \selectfont}
```

But it is not working properly. Not sure if the length is being rounded to integer, of if the `calc` multiplication just can't operate on command parameters.

**EDIT 1:** I tried to change 1.2 to 12, but the output is the same. Thus, not really a rounding issue. Looks more like `calc` not liking to multiply parameter values.

**EDIT 2:** Temporary solution:

```
 \def\Palatino#1{
   \newlength{\tmpLength}
   \setlength{\tmpLength}{#1 * \real{1.2}}
   \normalfont\fontsize{#1}{\tmpLength}\PalatinoFont\selectfont}
```

Keeping no answer, in case someone can explain why the length is needed.

Comment: Please provide a full MWE.  What I hacked together, I can't see the problem you are having.  So, obviously, my MWE doesn't look like yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to achieve, but you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xfp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily{\PalatinoFont}{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\newcommand{\Palatino}[1]{%
  \normalfont
  \fontsize{#1}{\fpeval{1.2*(#1)}}%
  \PalatinoFont
}

\begin{document}

\Palatino{15}\lipsum[2]

\Palatino{5}\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```